# How can i extract only the destination ports from a TCPDUMP file

Tags: linux, bash

i currently have a script in bash that extract the destination IPs and ports only from the Host IP ( me )
I need to sort the destination Ports in a separate File.

the command i use now for making the capture:

```
tcpdump -G 15 -W 1 -w myscript15s -i enp0s3 -nnvvS src 10.0.2.15 and dst portrange '1-65535'
```

Does anyone what command can i use to put in a separate document only the destination ports? 
I found you can only sort IPs but maybe i didn't search throughly enough :(

[Packet capture script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzmdU.jpg)
[Packet capture output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjC8U.jpg)

// Script for making the capture

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Select your capture option: "
read capture
echo "You selected  $catpure"
echo
if [ $capture == "Option1" ];
then
echo
tcpdump -G 15 -W 1 -w myscript15s -i enp0s3 -nnvvS src 10.0.2.15 and dst portrange '1-65535'
tcpdump -ttttnnr myscript15s
cp myscript15s captura
elif [ $capture == "Option2" ]
then
echo
tcpdump -G 600 -W 1 -w myscript600s -i enp0s3 -nnvvS src 10.0.2.15 and dst portrange '1-65535'
else
echo "Incorect option .."
fi
echo
echo "The end"
echo
```

/// output - placed only first 2 lines to get the ideea

```
2018-06-26 15:42:21.261263 IP 10.0.2.15.54178 > 10.18.0.22.53:19272 [1au] A? detectportal.firefox.com.(53)
2018-06-26 15:42:21.261418 IP 10.0.2.15.51118 > 10.18.0.22.53:31437+ [1au] AAAA? detectportal.firefox.com.(53)
```

Comment: Can you post tcpdump example output?

Comment: i added 2 pics:  
1 with the Script i am using 
1 with the Output that is received 

Maybe it will give a clearer view.

Comment: Well, can't you copy this into a `<code>` section? [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Added the code now. A little new to this. still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 1):

One way that could achieve this would be using tshark to read the capture while applying display filters, sorting as needed then writing the output to a file:

```
 tshark -r your_capture_file.pcap -T fields -e udp.dstport -e tcp.dstport | sort | uniq > results.txt
```

If you wish to also include the protocol name in your results you can add it in the filter as well:

```
 tshark -r your_capture_file.pcap -T fields -e _ws.col.Protocol -e udp.dstport -e tcp.dstport | sort | uniq > results.txt
```

Note that using the above method will take care of everything in a single command however the output resulted will contain blank UDP port columns for TCP traffic and blank TCP port columns for UDP traffic which may pose an issue.

In order to avoid this, you can simply run the command twice, once per protocol:

**TCP**

```
tshark -r your_capture_file.pcap -T fields -e tcp.dstport | sort | uniq > results.txt
```

**UDP**

```
tshark -r your_capture_file.pcap -T fields -e udp.dstport | sort | uniq >> results.txt
```

Take note that the second run should use the >> operator instead of the > one to append data to the results file.